# Custom error not working during test

Tags: testing, mocha, modifiers

I tried to use custom error instead of using a require in modifier like so:

```
    modifier tokenExist(bytes32 ticker) {
    if(tokens[ticker].tickerAddress != address(0)) revert Exchange__TokenNotExist();  
    _;
}
```

When I tested it in the test script, I'm getting an VM exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'Exchange__TokenNotExist()'

It was working well when I use a normal require with the same syntax. Is there anything that I missed here?

here is the test script that I've made:

```
 it("should withdraw tokens", async () => {
    const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("100");

    await dex.connect(trader1).deposit(DAI, amount);
    await dex.connect(trader1).withdraw(DAI, amount);

    const balance = await dex.s_traderBalances(trader1.address, DAI);
    expect(balance).to.equal(0);
  });
```

This the function that I used with the modifier:

```
function withdraw(bytes32 ticker, uint amount) tokenExist(ticker) external {   
    require(s_traderBalances[msg.sender][ticker] >= amount, "balance too low");
    s_traderBalances[msg.sender][ticker] -= amount;
    IERC20(tokens[ticker].tickerAddress).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
}
```

Comment: I think You are checking for an address to be a zero address.
remove the `!` from `if(tokens[ticker].tickerAddress != address(0)) revert Exchange__TokenNotExist();` .
hope this helps

Comment: still doesnt work. I used the same syntax using require and it passed

Comment: Require is better option in these cases and the previous syntax was wrong beacause you didn't tell the modifier about what to do if the `if` blocks fails. `If` statements always comes with `else` statements. So better use `require ` in the modifiers to reduce complexity.
And the thing I said before about the `!` was also valid coz your code was saying that `if an address is nonzero address then revert` . so the function will revert everytime you call it.